# Find and replace text in a string using C#

Tags: c#, string, replace

Anyone know how I would find & replace text in a string? Basically I have two strings:

```
string firstS = "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/2wBDABQODxIPDRQSERIXFhQYHzMhHxwcHz8tLyUzSkFOTUlBSEZSXHZkUldvWEZIZoxob3p9hIWET2ORm4+AmnaBhH//2wBDARYXFx8bHzwhITx/VEhUf39/f39/f39/f39/f39/f39/f39/f39/f39/f39/f39/f39/f39/f39/f39/f39/f3//";

string secondS = "abcdefg2wBDABQODxIPDRQSERIXFh/f39/f39/f39/f39/f39/f39/f39/f39/f39/f39/f39/f39/f39/f39/f39/abcdefg";
```

I want to search `firstS` to see if it contains any sequence of characters that's in `secondS` and then replace it. It also needs to be replaced with the number of replaced characters in squared brackets:

> [NUMBER-OF-CHARACTERS-REPLACED]

For example, because `firstS` and `secondS` both contain "2wBDABQODxIPDRQSERIXFh" and "/f39/f39/f39/f39/f39/f39/f39/f39/f39/f39/f39/f39/f39/f39/f39/" they would need to be replaced. So then `firstS` becomes:

```
string firstS = "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/[22]QYHzMhHxwcHz8tLyUzSkFOTUlBSEZSXHZkUldvWEZIZoxob3p9hIWET2ORm4+AmnaBhH//2wBDARYXFx8bHzwhITx/VEhUf39[61]f3//";
```

Hope that makes sense. I think I could do this with Regex, but I don't like the inefficiency of it. Does anyone know of another, faster way?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does anyone know of another, faster way?

Yes, this problem actually has a proper name. It is called the [*Longest Common Substring*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem), and it has a [reasonably fast solution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem#Pseudocode).

Here is [an implementation on ideone](http://ideone.com/bx2OE). It finds and replaces all common substrings of ten characters or longer.

```
// This comes straight from Wikipedia article linked above:
private static string FindLcs(string s, string t) {
    var L = new int[s.Length, t.Length];
    var z = 0;
    var ret = new StringBuilder();
    for (var i = 0 ; i != s.Length ; i++) {
        for (var j = 0 ; j != t.Length ; j++) {
            if (s[i] == t[j]) {
                if (i == 0 || j == 0) {
                    L[i,j] = 1;
                } else {
                    L[i,j] = L[i-1,j-1] + 1;
                }
                if (L[i,j] > z) {
                    z = L[i,j];
                    ret = new StringBuilder();
                }
                if (L[i,j] == z) {
                    ret.Append(s.Substring( i-z+1, z));
                }
            } else {
                L[i,j]=0;
            }
        }
    }
    return ret.ToString();
}
// With the LCS in hand, building the answer is easy
public static string CutLcs(string s, string t) {
    for (;;) {
        var lcs = FindLcs(s, t);
        if (lcs.Length < 10) break;
        s = s.Replace(lcs, string.Format("[{0}]", lcs.Length));
    }
    return s;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**You need to be very careful between "Longest common substring and "longest common subsequence"**

For Substring: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem

For SubSequence: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem

**I would suggest you to also see few videos on youtube on these two topics**
http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=longest+common+substring&oq=longest+common+substring&gs_l=youtube.3..0.3834.10362.0.10546.28.17.2.9.9.2.225.1425.11j3j3.17.0...0.0...1ac.lSrzx8rr1kQ

http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=longest+common+subsequence&oq=longest+common+s&gs_l=youtube.3.0.0l6.2968.7905.0.9132.20.14.2.4.4.0.224.2038.5j2j7.14.0...0.0...1ac.4CYZ1x50zpc

you can find c# implementation of longest common subsequence here:

http://www.alexandre-gomes.com/?p=177

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Longest_common_subsequence

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue, but for word occurrences! so, I hope this can help. I used `SortedDictionary` and a binary search tree

```
/* Application counts the number of occurrences of each word in a string
   and stores them in a generic sorted dictionary. */
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class SortedDictionaryTest
{
   public static void Main( string[] args )
   {
      // create sorted dictionary
      SortedDictionary< string, int > dictionary = CollectWords();

      // display sorted dictionary content
      DisplayDictionary( dictionary );
   } 

   // create sorted dictionary 
   private static SortedDictionary< string, int > CollectWords()
   {
      // create a new sorted dictionary
      SortedDictionary< string, int > dictionary =
         new SortedDictionary< string, int >();

      Console.WriteLine( "Enter a string: " ); // prompt for user input
      string input = Console.ReadLine(); 

      // split input text into tokens
      string[] words = Regex.Split( input, @"\s+" );

      // processing input words
      foreach ( var word in words )
      {
         string wordKey = word.ToLower(); // get word in lowercase

         // if the dictionary contains the word
         if ( dictionary.ContainsKey( wordKey ) )
         {
            ++dictionary[ wordKey ];
         } 
         else
            // add new word with a count of 1 to the dictionary
            dictionary.Add( wordKey, 1 );
      } 

      return dictionary;
   } 

   // display dictionary content
   private static void DisplayDictionary< K, V >(
      SortedDictionary< K, V > dictionary )
   {
      Console.WriteLine( "\nSorted dictionary contains:\n{0,-12}{1,-12}",
         "Key:", "Value:" );

      /* generate output for each key in the sorted dictionary
        by iterating through the Keys property with a foreach statement*/
      foreach ( K key in dictionary.Keys )
         Console.WriteLine( "{0,- 12}{1,-12}", key, dictionary[ key ] );

      Console.WriteLine( "\nsize: {0}", dictionary.Count );
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably dog slow, but if you're willing to incur some technical debt and need something now for prototyping, you could use LINQ.

```
string firstS = "123abc";
string secondS = "456cdeabc123";
int minLength = 3;

var result = 
    from subStrCount in Enumerable.Range(0, firstS.Length)
    where firstS.Length - subStrCount >= 3
    let subStr = firstS.Substring(subStrCount, 3)
    where secondS.Contains(subStr)
    select secondS.Replace(subStr, "[" + subStr.Length + "]");
```

Results in

```
 456cdeabc[3] 
 456cde[3]123
```